# How can I join 2 table together?

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to create a join table with 2 existing tables. something like below:

This is the first table queries and looks like this

https://ibb.co/sg2MXKf

```
SELECT
    DATEPART( week, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) AS [Week Income],
    DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) AS [Year],
    SUM ( dbo.Income.CardAmount ) AS [Total Card],
    SUM ( dbo.Income.CashAmount ) AS [Total Cash],
    SUM ( dbo.Income.TipsAmount ) AS [Total Tip],
    SUM ( dbo.Income.SalaryAmount ) AS [Total Salary],
    SUM ( dbo.Income.Adjustment ) AS [Total Adjustment] 
FROM
    dbo.Income 
GROUP BY
    DATEPART( week, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ),
    DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) 
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, dbo.Income.IncomeDate )
```

And this is the second table queries and looks like this

https://ibb.co/z8sRwpT

```
SELECT
    DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) AS [Week],
    COUNT (DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn )) AS [Expenses Count],
    DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) AS [Year],
    SUM ( dbo.Transactions.PaymentAmount ) AS [Total] 
FROM
    dbo.Transactions 
GROUP BY
    DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ),
    DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) 
ORDER BY
    DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn )
```

What I expected is something this. Both table 1 and 2 combined, and the total expenses added.

https://ibb.co/0DbZLYV

Comment: Don't post images, use text -- `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements. And especially don't post links to images. And links to images where one needs an account to be able to view the images are even worse.

Comment: No access to your private sharepoint instance, but I suspect what you're after is nested table expressions which would allow you to treat the results of each of those queries as a table in a join, then its just normal SQL to get the result you want from there.

Comment: Sorry guys for the image, because I'm still new, and not allow to upload the picture yet. I have edited with public image share anyway. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by SO folks, we cannot access the images that describe your expected results. However we understand that you are looking to `JOIN` the results of both queries that you are showing.

Here is how to do it : you turn each query into a subquery, and you `JOIN` them together on their common key fields ; in your use case, this must be `Year` and `Week`. The `ORDER BY` clause needs to be moved to the outer query. In the `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses, you can freely access all the fields from the subqueries, using the aliases that you defined (here `A` and `B`).

Sample code (you will have to adapt the `SELECT`, I cannot tell what you want it to look like) :

```
SELECT
    A.[Week Income],
    A.[Year],
    A.[Total] - B.[Total Salary] AS [Balance]
    ...
 FROM (           
    SELECT
        DATEPART( week, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) AS [Week Income],
        DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) AS [Year],
        SUM ( dbo.Income.CardAmount ) AS [Total Card],
        SUM ( dbo.Income.CashAmount ) AS [Total Cash],
        SUM ( dbo.Income.TipsAmount ) AS [Total Tip],
        SUM ( dbo.Income.SalaryAmount ) AS [Total Salary],
        SUM ( dbo.Income.Adjustment ) AS [Total Adjustment] 
    FROM
        dbo.Income 
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART( week, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ),
        DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Income.IncomeDate ) 
 ) AS A 
 LEFT JOIN (  
    SELECT
        DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) AS [Week],
        COUNT (DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn )) AS [Expenses Count],
        DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) AS [Year],
        SUM ( dbo.Transactions.PaymentAmount ) AS [Total] 
    FROM
        dbo.Transactions 
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART( wk, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ),
        DATEPART( YEAR, dbo.Transactions.PaymentMadeOn ) 
  ) AS B ON A.[Week Income] = B.[Week] AND A.[Year] = B.[Year]
ORDER BY
    A.[Year],
    A.[Week Income]
```

Comment: Sorry for the image, because I'm still new, and not allow to upload the picture yet, but the code seems work but the 45 and 46 not appear (please refer to my newly uploaded images)

Table 1 - https://ibb.co/sg2MXKf
Table 2 -https://ibb.co/z8sRwpT
Expect result - https://ibb.co/0DbZLYV

Comment: OK I guess that you want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, I updated my answer. PS : at some point it looks you will need to replace `NULL` with `0`, look at the relevant function in your RDBMS (`COALESCE` if you are running mssql)